# power bi line graph with x and y axes crossing at zero

Tags: powerbi, visualization, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, linechart

I've got this dataset:

[image]

Which produces a line graph like this:

[image]

I want the x and y axes to cross in the middle like this (excuse the shaky lines):

[image]

I can't see an option to do this with the power bi standard line chart (power bi version 2.123.684.0).
Is there either another standard visualisation I can use to get this result, or does anyone know of a paid component that does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the format pane, click Analytics and add two constant lines at 0.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After clicking on "Power BI Visual" within the new format pane, you will find the option for a Constant Line with multiple choices:

X-Axis Constant Line
Y-Axis Constant Line
Average Constant Line
Median Constant Line
Percentile Constant Line
You can insert an X-Axis line only when both metrics are present on the X and Y sides; otherwise, it will not be possible.